# run as administrator has more permissions than SYSTEM

Tags: windows-services, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz.NET program that I can run either as a service or in a console. The program requires administrator access. When running in a console "as Administrator", the program works fine. When running as a service under the SYSTEM account, the triggers aren't recognized.

What is the difference between "As Administrator" and SYSTEM? Why would SYSTEM be more restricted? How can I ensure that SYSTEM has the same privileges?

Comment: SYSTEM is not more restricted. Share code and errors, please. It's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem wasn't with permissions as I had suspected, rather it was with the difference in the way the process is started as a service vs console.

Our service for Quartz actually had another service that we added. The problem was that one of the services wasn't being installed. We assumed that we could just add it to the list of services to start, but that is not the case. The service must be installed.

To answer the question, there is no difference between "As Administrator" and SYSTEM other than when running "As Administrator" you are still authenticated as the logged on user. SYSTEM has full privileges on the computer, and so is not more restricted as Andrew Barber pointed out in the comments.